# Remove records based on template match in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to remove records based on a field , using template match but it does not seem to be working

Input:

```
<PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <endDate/>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>DATAOTHER</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>HIRED</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>DATAPOS</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
                        <EmpEmployment>
                <endDate/>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>DATAOTHER</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>HIRED</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>DATAPOS</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
        <customString2/>
    </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

If the eventReason is not HIRED it should be removed. Here is the XSLT code so far:

XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/PerPerson/PerPerson/employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav[not(EmpJob/eventReason = 'HIRED')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output required: EmpJob records where eventReason is not HIRED should be removed

```
<PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <endDate/>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>HIRED</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
                        <EmpEmployment>
                <endDate/>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob>
                        <eventReason>HIRED</eventReason>
                    </EmpJob>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
        <customString2/>
    </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

Comment: *"it does not seem to be working"* is not a good description of a problem. And *"it should be removed"* is not a good description of a result (what exactly is "it"?). Please edit your question and add the exact output you expect to get in this example.

Comment: I have added the details. My apologies

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `EmpJob` nodes, then make your template match `EmpJob`, not `jobInfoNav`:

```
<xsl:template match="EmpJob[not(eventReason = 'HIRED')]"/>
```

---

Note that a [match pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#patterns) does not have to include the full path. Unless you have other `EmpJob` elements elsewhere in the hierarchy, the above will suffice.